# Drupal large files upload and download

Tags: drupal, upload, web

I developed a web site using Drupal 6 and I need to allow users to upload and download large files (up to 200 MB). Can anyone tell me please how is this usually done? Because I don't know if this is best to do using HTTP, maybe there is other way.

The site is hosted in a dedicated web host and I don't have access to php.ini or other server configuration.

Which is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need to find out what PHP's upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are. Have a look at the output of php_info() to find current settings. If they are > 200MB, you're OK to use HTTP already using any Drupal module that deals with file uploads.

If either setting is smaller, you can try to alter them at runtime with ini_set(), .htaccess, or a couple of other methods as per [here](http://drupal.org/node/97193) but this may or may not work, depending on your host.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the values are: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`